# Deleting dropdown options leaves the last option visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a dropdown in ReactJS that is populated from localstorage. I also have a button that deletes the localstorage entries and at the same time updates the component so that the `<option>` tag containing the entries disappears too. I can delete up to the last entry, but when I press to delete on the last one it doesn't dissapear from the DOM. To make an example, let's say I have 3 entries, `Test1, Test2 and Test3`. I denote pressing the "Delete button" while specific entry is chosen with `-- Delete`. I start with deleting `Test2`:

(Imagine this is the dropdown)

`Initial State   |  after 1st Del   | after 2nd Del   | after 3rd Del  | ...`

`Test1           |  Test1           | Test1 -- Delete | Test1 --Delete | Test1`

`Test2 -- Delete |  Test3 -- Delete |`

`Test3           |`

So whatever I do, the last entry still appears. The actual entry is deleted from localstorage, but the DOM stays the same. If I reload the page, the entry dissapears and the dropdown is empty, which is what I want happening without reloading.

Here's what I got so far:

**Profile.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

function resetProfileForm() {
    document.getElementById("change-profile").selectedIndex = 0;
}

class Profile extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
            this.state = { 
                existingProfiles: [],
                currentSelectedProfile: ''
            };
        this.profilesHaveChanged = this.profilesHaveChanged.bind(this);
        this.profileChange = this.profileChange.bind(this);
        this.profileDeleteClick = this.profileDeleteClick.bind(this);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.profilesHaveChanged();
    }
    profilesHaveChanged() {
        var currentExistingProfiles = [];
        for (var profile in localStorage) {
            if (profile !== ''){
                currentExistingProfiles.push(<option key={profile} value={profile}>{profile}</option>)
            } 
        }
        if (currentExistingProfiles.length > 0) {
            resetProfileForm();
            this.setState({
                existingProfiles: currentExistingProfiles,
                currentSelectedProfile: currentExistingProfiles[0].key
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                currentSelectedProfile: ''
            })
        }
    }
    profileChange(a) {
        this.setState({
            currentSelectedProfile: a.target.value
        });
    }
    profileDeleteClick() {
        localStorage.removeItem(this.state.currentSelectedProfile);
        this.profilesHaveChanged();
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="changes">
                <h3>
                    Profiles
                </h3>
                <select 
                    value={this.props.currentSelectedProfile}
                    id="change-profile" 
                    onChange={this.profileChange}>
                        {this.state.existingProfiles}
                </select>
                <div className="button-container">
                    <Button onClick={this.profileDeleteClick} bsStyle="primary" bsSize="small" block>Delete</Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Profile;
```

Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong/missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: why you are using localstorage for that, why not storing the data directly in state variable  then generating the options from state ?

Comment: @MayankShukla Because the main objective of the app is to have profiles with different settings that can be loaded whenever needed. I have just put the part of deleting, but there is saving and loading profiles. It would be confusing to add unnecessary code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think issue is, you are not resetting the `existingProfiles` values in state variable when  all the items has been removed inside `else` condition in this function `profilesHaveChanged`.

Try this:

```
profilesHaveChanged() {
     var currentExistingProfiles = [];
     for (var profile in localStorage) {
         if (profile !== ''){
             currentExistingProfiles.push(<option key={profile} value={profile}>{profile}</option>)
          } 
     }
     if (currentExistingProfiles.length > 0) {
         resetProfileForm();
         this.setState({
             existingProfiles: currentExistingProfiles,
             currentSelectedProfile: currentExistingProfiles[0].key
         })
     } else {
         this.setState({
            currentSelectedProfile: '',
            existingProfiles: []   //added this line
         })
     }
}
```

Comment: Yeap, this works. I'm an idiot, thought I added it. Thanks.